# how to check if actions originated by an object has errors

Tags: php, web-services, asynchronous, prestashop

I'm working on prestashop, and implementing a webservice thinghy. I has a Huge collection of data, that I would like to insert in prestashop, using web service. I have tried to send chunks of data, and all seems to work well, but when I start the real script, with real data, something goes wrong, I'll try to explain it. I want to insert all the attribute combination for all the products, so, basically, I have the two IDs of the two attributes something like:

> colour : Red (ID: 1300)
>
> Size : XXL (ID:1934)

I also have the ID of the product I want to associate with them, so for example `17909`. All those information are taken from the database "directly" so without web service, well, now I would like to send them to web service and tell the web service it must add this combination for this product, the call is something like:

```php
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$opt = array('resource' => 'combinations'); 
$xml_ins = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/combinations?schema=blank')); 
                                                    
$combinations = $xml_ins->children()->children();                                       
$combinations->id_product = $id_prodotto;                                       
$combinations->quantity = $quantita_combinazione;
$combinations->minimal_quantity = '1';
$combinations->default_on = '1';
                                                    
unset($combinations->associations->product_option_values->product_option_value);
$combinations->associations->product_option_values->addChild('product_option_value')->addChild('id', $id_colore);
$combinations->associations->product_option_values->addChild('product_option_value')->addChild('id', $id_taglia);                               
                                                    
                                                
$opt = array('resource' => 'combinations');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml_ins->asXML();        
$xml_ins = $webService->add($opt);
```

Is there a way to know if the last line `$xml_ins = $webService->add($opt);` has executed the right way? Actually I surrounded everything with a `try catch` but after about 10 mins of execution, all the combinations but some dozen, has been inserted. I have no errors and the script simply... stops... It is like that having too many try catch opened inside a nested loop is a bit mh...heavy and some of them are missing...

I would like to understand if that call is an async call... or something that could remain "open" and stack with all the other calls after that... A sort of nested open object call, if you know what I mean.

Comment: If it were asynchronous you'd be more likely to have the opposite problem of the script ending immediately without getting any data back. Other than that I'm not sure, haven't used PrestaShop...

Comment: mh... you are right I must think about it.

Comment: It looks like you're using the REST web service. In which case it's probably using curl to send and receive HTTP requests behind the scenes. curl has an option to set a timeout...you can also get the response content and status code...but I'm not sure how or whether PrestaShop's wrapper API lets you do those things.

Comment: Have you tried it with a smaller request that's successful? What does adding var_dump($xml_ins) at the end of your script display?

Comment: I just realized the problem might not be the web service at all but rather that you need to increase your max PHP script execution time and/or memory limit.

Comment: well, these are all nice ideas, ok here the things:
- now i'll check for those CURL timeouts.
at the beginning of the script, and every function change i have put a set_time_limit(30); but i don't know if it's enough...

Comment: I think that should cover you for max execution time but not if it's an out of memory error...check your PHP error log, it might show an error that didn't show up on-screen, it should show an error there if it ran out of memory or took too long. If not then it's probably an issue with the way you're using the web service.